# How to show column separators in Markdown tables with PDF output?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am trying to output a table from Markdown to PDF using pandoc, but the column separators don't appear in the output. Specifically, I'm trying to copy this table from Wikipedia: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsHWN.png

However, this is the result I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6E56.png

Apart from the poor quality of the icons, I would like to see a visual separator between the columns. Is it possible to add that?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add vertical lines in PDF tables generated with Pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638906/how-do-you-add-vertical-lines-in-pdf-tables-generated-with-pandoc)

Comment: I can't find a valid solution. It's really unfortunate that pandoc does not support this feature, I'll try to use LaTeX directly. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.